# LibGDX & Google Play Games not working

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play, google-play-games

I wrote a game in `LibGDX`, and implemented `AdMob` (without problems) and tried to implement also Google Play Games. Unfortunatelly, game behaves now very strange. It works perfectly on signed debug `APK`, but magic happens on signed release `APK`. Most of the time it works perfectly fine, but sometimes logging into account throws empty error and when I try to give myself test achievement, it crashes becouse of empty variable. Even funnier stuff happens when I try to publish it on Play Store, then it stops working completely!

I've tried many things: adding silent login, trying on different accounts, different devices, added `FireBase`, publishing app both on Beta and Official Google Play channel.

The worst thing is it gives completely no error message in `logcat`.

I've used

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
```

on android project.

How can I fix such behaviour?

Comment: If  it's perfectly working on debug APK, that should imply something. Did you [sign your app with a release key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing)?

Comment: If it wasn't signed, Google PLay Console won't let me upload APK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be solved, I've added second app to the game service, but this time linking it with actual Google Play item instead of lone package name.

Answer (score 0):

What Play Games implementation are you using? If you use your own, no one can help you why it crashes or what problems there are.

Check out https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-gamesvcs for using Play Games with libGDX. This is a stable and well-tested implementation.

Comment: I've tried to use it, but it wouldn't work. Since then I've refactored the code, and maybe I can try again.